How to pass argument to filament table action
->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
                \Filament\Tables\Actions\Action::make('Generate QR Codes')
                    ->label('QRCodes')
                    ->action('generateAndDownloadQRCodes')
                    ->color('success')
                // ->record(fn($record) => $record->id)
                ->arguments(fn($record) => ['id' => $record->id])
            ])

is there a way i can pass the id of the item in the row to the action function, the argument and record functions both are not working

You can do this:
Action::make('Generate QR Codes')
    ->action(function ($record) {
        // ... 
    })

